# Regarding change of measure

Tags: stochastic-processes

Suppose a Gaussian process $\{B_t\}$, apparently $2^{B_t}$ is not a martingale. Can someone teach me how to change the measure so that $2^{B_t}$ is a martingale?

Thanks.

Comment: Is $(B_t)_t$ supposed to be a Brownian motion or indeed an arbritrary Gaussian process?

Comment: Sorry. Should be the former, i.e $N(0,\sigma^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B=(B_t)_{t\geqslant0}$ is a standard Brownian motion, then each $M^{(a)}_t=\mathrm e^{aB_t-a^2t/2}$ defines a martingale. For every $c$, $\mathrm e^{cB_t}\cdot M^{(a)}_t=\mathrm e^{(c+a)B_t-a^2t/2}$ also defines a martingale if and only if $a^2=(c+a)^2$, that is, $a=-c/2$. Thus,
$$
\left.\frac{\mathrm dQ}{\mathrm dP}\right|_{\mathcal F_t}=M^{(-c/2)}_t=\mathrm e^{-cB_t/2-c^2t/8}
$$
defines a probability measure $Q$ such that $X_t=\mathrm e^{cB_t}$ defines a $Q$-martingale $X$. Use this for $c=\ln2$.

Just (a special case of) [Girsanov theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girsanov_theorem).